# In shell config scripts, how can I account for differences between coreutils on BSD compared to GNU?

Tags: bash, bashrc, bsd, gnu

Up until this month, my shell configs have been pretty simple (just a `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` with some aliases mainly), but I have been refactoring it so I can get different behavior depending on whether I'm using zsh, and bash. They first source a generic shell config file that should work for whatever, then specialize for the specific shell being used (I symlink to this).

I was surprised today when `ls` stopped working. It turned out that during refactoring `.bashrc`, there was an alias

```
alias ls='ls --color=always'
```

that was breaking things for `ls` in bash on Terminal in OSX. Once I saw that BSD `ls` likes `-G` for color, but GNU (or whatever was on Ubuntu) likes `--color`, it was clear that quite a few options differ.

My question is, what is the best way to account for differences in options and such between BSD and GNU coreutils? Should I test for an env variable in `if` blocks to see what OS is being used and apply correct behavior? Or does it make more sense to make separate config files for each OS?

While answers to these questions may be subjective, it seems like a rundown of the scope of differences between BSD and GNU coreutils and strategies to work around these to make a generic config usable on most *nix would be fairly objective.

Comment: Changing shells won't fix anything, and `ls -c` is different from `ls --color`.  Edited your question to fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only reliable way to write scripts that support different operating systems is to only use features that are defined by POSIX.

For things like your personal shell configurations, you can use hacks that fit your specific use case. Something like the following is ugly, but will accomplish the goal.

```
if ls --version 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'coreutils'; then
    alias ls='ls --color=always'
else
    alias ls='ls -G'
fi
```

Comment: I've been playing around with different methods, and I think your "ugly" solution is pretty good and not even that ugly. As it turns out, I hadn't noticed the mismatch in options for ls earlier because I was using GNU coreutils from Ports. This is an example why doing an 'if' on $OSTYPE can fail to deliver desired results.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the error that comes from "if ls --version" when GNU coreutils aren't present (but still be able to test for coreutils)?

Comment: Oh, nevermind about suppressing the error. I just redirect stderr to /dev/null before piping to grep and it works as I'd like.

Comment: Rather than look for `coreutils` explicitly, why not just test whether the color flag works, e.g. `if ls --color=auto -d / >/dev/null 2>&1; then ...`.

Comment: @mikel if you are only concerned about color (like in the example), that is fine. If you care about other features as well, checking for coreutils is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Littering the code with `if` statements to perform a switch on the type of *coreutils* does work, however the clean programming solution for handling different types is to use [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). Since this is Bash, we don't have polymorphism per se, but I've been messing around with a way to fake it. The only requirement is that your `.bashrc` file etc. be organized into functions.

First I create a test for the *coreutils* platform type:

```
get_coreutils_platform() {
    local ls_version="$(ls --version 2>/dev/null)"
    if [[ "$ls_version" == *"GNU coreutils"* ]]; then
        echo gnu
    else
        echo bsd
    fi
}
```

Then we can dispatch based on the type:

```
platform=$(get_coreutils_platform)
define_standard_aliases_$platform
configure_shell_vars_$platform
```

Here's the **BSD** implementation:

```
define_standard_aliases_bsd() {
    define_standard_aliases
}

configure_shell_vars_bsd() {
    configure_shell_vars
    export CLICOLOR=1
}
```

(Note we use the `CLICOLOR` variable to turn on colors instead of using an `alias`, which seems a littler cleaner)

And the **GNU** impelementation:

```
define_standard_aliases_gnu() {
    define_standard_aliases
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
}

configure_shell_vars_gnu() {
    configure_shell_vars
}
```

For completeness' sake, here's a sample implementation of the "abstract base":

```
define_standard_aliases() {
    alias ll='ls -l'
    alias l.='ls -d .*'
}

configure_shell_vars() {
    export EDITOR=vim
}
```

Comment: This is much cleaner, unless you're on the 0.1% of systems with e.g. GNU ls but not GNU cat installed (maybe it's really old and they have fileutils but not textutils).  I'd be tempted to use `ls` in your dispatcher rather than `cat`, especially since none of your aliases involve `cat`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need `--color=auto` in your second and third aliases, since the first alias adds that option to `ls`.

Comment: @Mikel whoa, I totally didn't realize that `alias` was recursive. That lets me make the example much simpler.

Comment: Much better. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I have wrapper scripts to handle things like this rather than extra complication in the .bashrc
For example here is my l script that handles your case here in a cross platform way:

http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/l